# make file is throwing below two error

Tags: c++, string, makefile

Hello i have created four file fn.cpp header.h,main.cpp and makefile 
I  am getting two error plz help to fix it.

1. fn.cpp:1 error: string was not declared in this scope? why?
2. fn.cpp:2 error :expected ',' or ';' before '{' token?

header.h:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int fn(string);
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
string s= " hello world";
int main()
{
    fn(s):
}
```

fn.cpp:

```
int fn(string ss)
{
    printf("%s",ss);
}
```

makefile:

```
all:hello
hello:main.o fn.o
tab   g++ main.o fn.o-o hello
main.o:main.cpp
tab  g++ -c main.cpp
fn.o:fn.cpp
tab g++ -c fn.cpp
```

Comment: Please, indent your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::string` class is defined in the `<string>` header. Include that instead of the C library's `<string.h>` header.

Also, you need to include `"header.h"` from both source files.

Finally, you can't pass a `string` object directly to `printf`; that's a C function which knows nothing of C++ classes. Either use C++ I/O:

```
std::cout << ss;
```

or faff around with C-style strings:

```
printf("%s", ss.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

many small "out of c++ style" problems :)

use header `#include <string>` and avoid `printf` if you can, better use `cout`

c++ lovers would like this a little bit more:

fn.h

```
#include<string>
void fn(const std::string&);
```

fn.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fn.h"

void fn(const std::string& ss)
{
    printf(ss.c_str());
}
```

hello.cpp

```
#include "fn.h"

std::string s = " hello world";

int main()
{
    fn(s);
}
```

Makefile

```
all: hello

hello: hello.cpp fn.o
```